# Trouble following Microsoft's WCF tutorial

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to follow Microsoft's WCF tutorial and am on this step: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx

Unfortunately when I run this command:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service
```

it gives me a 404 error.  The service is running and I am able to successfuly reach it through the web browser by going to: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service

What am I doing wrong?  In case it helps I posted all the code for the sample host I'm using below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri BaseAddress = new Uri("http://locoalhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service");
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), BaseAddress);

            try
            {
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                selfHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An expection occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }

        [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
        public interface ICalculator
        {
            [OperationContract]
            double Add(double n1, double n2);

            [OperationContract]
            double Subtract(double n1, double n2);

            [OperationContract]
            double Multiply(double n1, double n2);

            [OperationContract]
            double Divide(double n1, double n2);
        }

        public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
        {
            public double Add(double n1, double n2)
            {
                double result = n1 + n2;
                Console.WriteLine("Received Add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
                // Code added to write output to the console window.
                Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
                return result;
            }

            public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
            {
                double result = n1 - n2;
                Console.WriteLine("Received Subtract({0},{1})", n1, n2);
                Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
                return result;
            }

            public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
            {
                double result = n1 * n2;
                Console.WriteLine("Received Multiply({0},{1})", n1, n2);
                Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
                return result;
            }

            public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
            {
                double result = n1 / n2;
                Console.WriteLine("Received Divide({0},{1})", n1, n2);
                Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing wrong is you have a typo localhost (you have locoalhost)

```
Uri BaseAddress = new Uri("http://locoalhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service");
```

You can also download fiddler @ http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to see the traffic and the requests being made from the client code.  that will provide the next clue.  It's indispensable when troubleshooting http services.

http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Also, make sure your config is good.  See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734663.aspx